# Fixing SQL and loop to auto place data into CGridView

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, yii

I'm currently using SQL to create a new dataprovider to fill my cgridview out.

The issue I'm having is that I'm having to target ID's directly of the dynamic questions that users create, and add them one by one to the form view.

For example, the SQL I'm using is

```
MAX(CASE WHEN uv.user_type_variables_id = 1 THEN uv.value ELSE NULL END) Question1,
MAX(CASE WHEN uv.user_type_variables_id = 2 THEN uv.value ELSE NULL END) Question2,
MAX(CASE WHEN uv.user_type_variables_id = 3 THEN uv.value ELSE NULL END) Question3,
MAX(CASE WHEN uv.user_type_variables_id = 4 THEN uv.value ELSE NULL END) Question4,
MAX(CASE WHEN uv.user_type_variables_id = 5 THEN uv.value ELSE NULL END) Question5,
MAX(CASE WHEN uv.user_type_variables_id = 6 THEN uv.value ELSE NULL END) Question6
```

and I've had to put each one in the view like

```
 array(
            'header' => 'Question1',
            'name' => 'uv.user_type_variables_id',
            'type' => 'raw',
            'value' => '$data[\'Question1\']',
        ),
        array(
            'header' => 'Question2',
            'name' => 'uv.user_type_variables_id',
            'type' => 'raw',
            'value' => '$data[\'Question2\']',
        ),
```

Naturally that doesn't work when I don't know the ID and can't programmatically changethe view everytime the user adds a field!

How do I go about targetting the SQL like above, then dynamically looping around and placing into the gridview without having to manually put in the fields?

I am only presuming that it is possible to target it this way, I can't think of any other way to target each individual ID and name it so I can place it in the grid without declaring the ID

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  SELECT user_type_variables_id, 
         max(value), 
         row_number() over (order by user_type_variables_id) as n
    FROM uv
 --WHERE uv.user_type_variables_id BETWEEN 1 AND 6
GROUP BY user_type_variables_id
```

Comment: The issue I'm having is that I need to then name each question and assign it to question 1 etc

Comment: you can do this by one query, and return ROW_NUMBER() to use it as the name of query and fill array in loop, or query in loop "for(;;)" , first asking about count(1) of uv.user_type_variables_id